# Post Json Data using google app script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, google-apps-script, content-type

I am posting a as shown below:

```
function myFunction() {
       var headers = {
      };
      var jsondata = {
      "operator_name": "eee",
      "data":  [
          {
              "first_name": "CHaahal"
          }              
              ]
                        };

    var payload = JSON.stringify(jsondata);

    var url = "http://some_server.com";
    var options = {
    "method": "POST",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload
  };

    Logger.log(options);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var responseCode = parseInt(response.getResponseCode());
  Logger.log(response);
  Logger.log(responseCode);

}
```

At the server side, I am getting an **HTML** request instead of json request.
When I hit the same API using Postman with the headers set, the api works. Please suggest

Comment: Not sure but just maybe try sending the jsondata as it is without stringifying it.

Comment: Like Farhan suggested do this `var payload = jsondata` since you set the `"contentType": "application/json"` you dont need to stringfy it.

Comment: Tried without stringifying --
`Error occurred while parsing request parameters.
Contents:

operator_name=eee&data=%5BLjava.lang.Object;@247601f9%0A`